# Issues using NSUSerDefaults to store permanent data

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm having difficulty with using `NSUSerDefaults` to store permanent data, basically I have an app which have two global variables, `countSeconds` and `totalSeconds`, both are of type int. `countSeconds` is increased by the timer and `totalSeconds` is supposed to be the total time ever recorded (I want this to be permanent storage) 
There is also two view controllers, one is a timer and has the code:

```
@IBAction func addTimeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    totalSeconds += countSeconds
    timer.invalidate()
    countSeconds = 0
    timerDisplay.text = ("00:00")

    if ahoyCaptin > 0 {
        ahoyCaptin--
    }
}
```

Which basically stops the timer and sets the timer value `countSeconds`to 0. The `ahoyCapti` code is just to prevent multiple timers being ran at once so is irrelevant to this question.

The other view controller displays the long term data (the stuff I would like to store with permanent storage (`totalSeconds`)) It has the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){

    var timerDisplayyo = display(time: totalSeconds, label: totalTime, prefix: "Total: ")

    let savedData = countSeconds
    userDefaults.setObject(countSeconds, forKey: "key")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var yarr: Int? = userDefaults.objectForKey("key") as Int?
    if yarr == nil {
        totalSeconds = 0
    }
    else {
        totalSeconds += yarr!
    }

}
```

`timerDisplayyo` is a function to display the time in a nice format, and takes the argument of `totalSeconds`. As far as I'm aware the first code segment creates a constant which stores the value of `countSeconds` (the variable I want to store permanently) which is updated frequently with synchronize.

The second code segment creates a variable called `yarr` which is an optional Int, that's equal to the stored value. If the optional is nil (i.e. value isn't stored?) the value of `totalSeconds = 0`, and if it isn't nil the value is unwrapped and added to `totalSeconds`.

Unfortunately it seems the value isn't being stored/being accessed, because whenever I restart the app it has a value of 0. Either that or it isn't being displayed.

Really sorry this question is so long, thanks!

Comment: in this line `userDefaults.setObject(countSeconds, forKey: "key")`, you are storing `countSeconds` as key. Was it supposed to be `totalSeconds`?

Answer (score 0):

There are the methods `userDefaults.setInteger` and `.integerForKey`.  Try with those instead of the object ones.